# Concatenate texts in a row based on a condition

Tags: r, text, merge, concatenation, string-concatenation

I have the data like the following.

```
a <- structure(list(Title = c("AAADE", "BBBCF", "NBNJHB", "TTTTT", "VVVFF", 
"AASFE", "DDDFFF", "ERFRR", "AAAAAA", "ERERE"), 
Year = c("2004", "2004", "2004", "2004", "2004", "2004", "2005", "2005", "2005", "2005")),
.Names = c("Title", "Year"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
a
    Title Year
1   AAADE 2004
2   BBBCF 2004
3  NBNJHB 2004
4   TTTTT 2004
5   VVVFF 2004
6   AASFE 2004
7  DDDFFF 2005
8   ERFRR 2005
9  AAAAAA 2005
10  ERERE 2005
```

I want to concatenate the rows based on the same year. I am trying to use 'tm' package functions which are not helping me to get like the following.

```
Title                                     Year      
AAADE BBBCF NBNJHB TTTTT VVVFF AASFE      2004
DDDFFF ERFRR AAAAAA ERERE                 2005
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with(a, data.frame(Title = tapply(Title, Year, paste, collapse = ' '), Year = unique(Year)))
```

Result:

```
                                Title Year
 AAADE BBBCF NBNJHB TTTTT VVVFF AASFE 2004
            DDDFFF ERFRR AAAAAA ERERE 2005
```

Answer (score 3):

A more direct approach is to use `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(Title ~ Year, a, paste, collapse = " ")
#   Year                                Title
# 1 2004 AAADE BBBCF NBNJHB TTTTT VVVFF AASFE
# 2 2005            DDDFFF ERFRR AAAAAA ERERE
```

You can do `aggregate(Title ~ Year, a, paste, collapse = " ")[names(a)]` if the order of the columns is important to you.

Stepping up from `aggregate`, you can look into "data.table" and "dplyr", both of which would be more efficient for larger datasets.

Here's "dplyr":

```
library(dplyr)
a %>% group_by(Year) %>% summarise(Title = paste(Title, collapse = " "))
# Source: local data frame [2 x 2]
# 
#   Year                                Title
# 1 2004 AAADE BBBCF NBNJHB TTTTT VVVFF AASFE
# 2 2005            DDDFFF ERFRR AAAAAA ERERE
```

Here's "data.table":

```
library(data.table)
A <- as.data.table(a)
A[, list(Title = paste(Title, collapse = " ")), by = Year]
#    Year                                Title
# 1: 2004 AAADE BBBCF NBNJHB TTTTT VVVFF AASFE
# 2: 2005            DDDFFF ERFRR AAAAAA ERERE
```